# how to use twilio video api python?

Tags: django, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

I would like to implement twilio video API in my Django project but i didn't really understand the documentation. I managed to create a room following this example:

```
from twilio.rest import Client

api_key_sid = "SKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
api_key_secret = "your_api_key_secret"
client = Client(api_key_sid, api_key_secret)

room = client.video.rooms.create(unique_name='DailyStandup')

print(room.sid)
```

What should I do after that? How can I access the room and start the chat?

Comment: did you find a way to implement it?

Comment: hi no the documentation is little bit confusing and my english is not so good

Comment: take a look at this [link](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js/blob/865fb51e9d363e6c6ee6406c7df28e2582888f9f/quickstart/src/index.js) on github